# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon SSD overheating

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, thinkpad

I recently bought a used Thinkpad X1 Carbon, it had Windows 7 installed, and on a first check, the SanDisk SSD ran around 43-45 degrees, i then installed Windows 8.1 and on installing Visual Studio 2013, i watched it rise to 56 degrees.

Ive never owned a SSD equipped laptop before, only HDDs ones, so this temperature is alarming to me, now it doesnt go below 49 degrees even idle, and the CPU stays in the range 50-65 degrees. Ive read that SSDs run on different temperatures than HDDs and on SanDisk official page, it says that the range of operations on the drive is 0-70 degrees.

What can u tell me about this readings, i took them with CrystalDiskInfo, and if it helps, i havent yet installed any drivers to it, including the ones related to the solid drive, dont know if that makes a difference. The readings also show that the Power On Count was 1400 and the Power On Hours of the drive were 880 hours.

Based on these readings, is there reason to be alarmed with this laptop? Should i run even more tests, or even worse, return it while my warranty is still up?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Given the thin design of the laptop, it is very possible that the SSD is installed very close to your heat-generating CPU/GPU/APU so this temperature is likey to be completely unavoidable.

Comment: I also read that these readings are almost always incorrect, given that SSDs dont even have thermometers, is this correct, does that mean all this heat is coming from other sources and the SSD is just there minding its own business, probably running cool? After, was confused me was that even with those readings, i felt it slightly warm, but not hot...

Comment: It's just really hard to tell whether or not that reading is correct. It is very likely that the laptop is actually using an mSATA SSD so you would have to figure out the SSD model number through your device manager and then check out the spec sheet to see if it has an onboard thermal sensor. If not then the temperature is being reported by an external sensor which may or may not be reliable.